# Twisted - Update web page content without reloading

Tags: python, http, twisted

There is code that displays current time on web page:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
import time

class ClockPage(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "<html><body>%s</body></html>" % (time.ctime(),)

resource = ClockPage()
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8880, factory)
reactor.run()
```

How can I modify it to update output time every second without reloading page? Should I use javascript(ajax/jquery) to send GET requests with fixed intervals or is it possible to do in python code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>
```

into returned html for reloading every 5 seconds.

**UPD**

For partial page update you need for AJAX query for partial page data:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
import time


page = """
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="timer">
      %s
    </div>
  </body>
    <script>
      function update_timer() {
        $.get("/timer", function(data) {
            $("#timer").replaceWith(data);
            window.setTimeout(update_timer, 1000);
        });
      }

      window.setTimeout(update_timer, 1000);
    </script>
</html>
"""


class ClockPage(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return page % (time.ctime(),)


class ClockSubelem(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
        return str(time.ctime())


resource = ClockPage()
timer = ClockSubelem()
resource.putChild("timer", timer)
factory = Site(resource)
reactor.listenTCP(8880, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: > without reloading page